# Scrapyd pass parameters when deploying

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

This is a simple example of a scrapy.cfg file:

```
[settings]
default = crawly.settings

[deploy:s1]
url = http://localhost:6800
project = my_project
```

I wanna know if I could pass any parameters to my scrapyd instance using this file. What I wanna do is to pass a parameter to one of my middlewares. You can pass parameters to your spider or override your settings but not anything with middlewares. I was thinking if a parameter like `project` could be passed to myserver, I could use that in my middleware.

Comment: Downvote without a comment!? nice.

Comment: how is it better than using settings.py?

Comment: I need that argument to be different for different servers.

Answer (score 0):

check out [this corresponding](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/388) on scrapy github, check the code if they ended up integrating the suggested change or take pablo advice for post egg generation